# How can I take the cache value from request anather application in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I can get value on main application on in memory cache. But cache is null on requests from another application.

```
 public override object Get(string key)
        {
            object item;
            try
            {
                item = _cache.Get(key);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                item = null;
                Trace.WriteLine("Cache Get() Hata oluşt." + ex.Message);
                throw new Exception("Cache Get() Hata oluşt." + ex.Message);
            }
            return item;
        }
......
 var value= cachedManager.Get("11287");  --> value is coming
....
but on web api
value is null
```

Why don't take the value on cache, when request another application

Comment: What kind of cache do you use? How cache is configured in application? Show more code.

Comment: Is the request coming *from* another application *to* the same server-side application, or is the request coming *from* the same browser *to* two different server-side applications?  It's not really clear what you're trying to describe.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I use ObjectCache.  
I guess the cache is private. I cannot access the cache in requests sent through another application.

Comment: the request coming from another application to the same server-side application